# MySQL count problem

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to count how many times a tag has been entered into the database and display the number of times it has been entered along with the tag into the database just like here on StackOverflow but I can't seem to be able to do it can someone help me?

So far I can get the tag but not the count.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is my MySQL & PHP code.

```
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT tags.*, posts_tags.* 
                             FROM tags 
                             INNER JOIN posts_tags ON tags.id = posts_tags.tag_id
                             GROUP BY tags.tag
                             ORDER BY tags.tag ASC");

if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbc)) {
    $tag = $row['tag'];

    echo '<a href="http://localhost/tags/">' . $tag . '</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try the following:

```
SELECT      tags.tag, COUNT(DISTINCT posts_tags.post_id) as number_of_tags
FROM        tags 
INNER JOIN  posts_tags ON tags.id = posts_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY    tags.tag
ORDER BY    tags.tag ASC;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (id int, tag varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE posts_tags (post_id int, tag_id int);

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, 'javascript');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2, 'php');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, 'mysql');

INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (5, 3);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (6, 1);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (7, 1);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (8, 2);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (9, 2);
INSERT INTO posts_tags VALUES (10, 1);
```

Result:

```
+------------+----------------+
| tag        | number_of_tags |
+------------+----------------+
| javascript |              5 |
| mysql      |              1 |
| php        |              4 |
+------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @helpME: Also check out OMG Ponies' answer, if you want to display tags where the count is `0`.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo but if I count the tag.id my count will always be 1 wouldn't it?

Comment: @helpME: Yes, in fact, I'm counting `post_id`... **UPDATE:** I had a typo in fact. `posts_tags.id` should have been `posts_tags.post_id`. Updated answer.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo but counting the tag.id is fine isn't it?

Comment: @helpME: It is actually, if you remove the `DISTINCT`. But I think it feels more natural to "count the distinct posts" for each tag.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo I assume you mean `posts_tags.tag_id` instead of `posts_tags.post_id`

Comment: @helpME: No, my example wouldn't have worked if I used `COUNT(DISTINCT posts_tags.tag_id)`. It would have returned `1` for each tag. This is because, the `tag_id` for each `tag` is obviously the same, and the `DISTINCT` bit would simply count `1,1,1,1,1` as `1` instead of `5`. You could use  `COUNT(posts_tags.tag_id)` (without `DISTINCT`), but I think it `COUNT(DISTINCT posts_tags.post_id)` reads better your intentions, since you are actually counting the *number of distinct posts* for each tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of tags, including those with a count of zero, use a LEFT JOIN:

```
   SELECT t.tag, 
          COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pt.post_id), 0) AS tag_count
     FROM TAGS t
LEFT JOIN POSTS_TAGS pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id
 GROUP BY t.tag
 ORDER BY t.tag
```

If you only want to see those that have been used one or more times, use an INNER JOIN:

```
  SELECT t.tag, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT pt.post_id) AS tag_count
    FROM TAGS t
    JOIN POSTS_TAGS pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.tag
ORDER BY t.tag
```

Comment: Yep, I forgot to mention the `LEFT JOIN` :)

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: Someone has to keep you on your toes :)

Comment: Why did you change the `COUNT` to `COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id)`? Wouldn't that display always `1` since you're grouping by tag?... A `GROUP_CONCAT(pt.tag_id)` would return something like `1,1,1,1,1`.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: You're mistaken - I changed the column referenced in the COUNT(DISTINCT from `pt.id` to `pt.tag_id` because I re-read & wasn't sure `pt.id` existed.  But you're right about the tally, and I see the column to be counted has been clarified so I'll update momentarily.  Good catch!